# JAVA:How to store gujrati(its other language) font in string?

Tags: java, string, netbeans-7

I have an application in java.

This application contains one text box and button.

Now I want to save Gujrati(other language)data in to database in click event of button.

How is it possible? Actually I done this think but my string return some other format.
So i don't know how to store gujrati data in to string ?

Comment: We won't be able to help unless you add details: what DB are you using? What DB access layer are you using? What encoding and nationalization settings do you use on app and DB side? Is this a web application, or a desktop one?

Comment: You say "Actually I done this thing" . What have you done?

Comment: @pradeep Simha:Actully i put on some gujrati word in text box and in next page when i retrive data using Request.Getparameter than it will not gujrati but its some other formet

Comment: @ppeterka:i am using mysql database and apache tomcat server.and data base acces layer is UTF general CI and this is a web application

Comment: can any one khow how i can store gujrati word in to string and than use this string in to secong page? if yes than give me some solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java works in Unicode. Gujarati characters have unicode values as shown [here](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0A80-0AFF)

You can directly store them in a string. However if you can't directly take Gujrati input you can use the character class like this

```
int c = 0x0A82;
String s = Character.toString((char)c);
//s is ં
```

And so on

Comment: thanks but its very difficult logic bcos i have to get all unbicode from gujrati than matches so its difficult for me

Comment: How are you taking input in gujju then?

Comment: :Actully i put on some gujrati word in text box and in next page when i retrive data using Request.Getparameter than it will not gujrati but its some other formet.and i want gujrati

Answer (score 3):

This works in Java as long as source code is in a Unicode-defined encoding, such as UTF-8 or UTF-16:

```
String ગઉજ = "ઋઊઘ";
```

That part solved, you need to specify where exactly your problem lies.

Comment: :i have java netbeans and net beans not supported gujrati language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with netbeans. It doesn't have to explicitly support gujarati for the Java program you write in it to be able to handle these characters because, as far as Unicode is concerned, the characters are no different from ordinary English ones.

Comment: Actully i put on some gujrati word in text box and in next page when i retrive data using Request.Getparameter than it will not gujrati but its some other formet.my concern is like that

Comment: This is a web application you are talking about. The problem occurs outside Java.

Comment: yes this is web application and proble is when i store gujrati word in string than get this string into next page than it will came in differnt formet

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes that you should make in you website

In JSP file change

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-16" pageEncoding="UTF-16"%>
```

and in **.property** file

save your text in uni-code format

Like this(here language of uni-code character is Gujarati

> global.Name = \u0AA8\u0ABE\u0AAE

This will surely work as it worked for me in struts2

output will be :

> નામ